# Linux script at parent directory expected

Tags: linux, shell, subdirectory

actually I am facing a quite ridiculous issue:

Basically I am trying to run a script by the command

```
/etc/scripts/subdir/script.x
```

Just to be clear, the script can be found at this location.

But when executing the command above I get the following message:

```
/etc/scripts/script.x: file or directory not found
```

So this means, for some mysterious reason, the script is expected to be directly inside "scripts", where it, of course, cannot be found.

I am trying to run this script as root, the script is owned by the user "user" and the permissions are 0755 (so everybody can read and execute it). The script is doing quite a bit more than echoing "Hello World", but not calling itself recursively.

Has anybody a clue, how this behavior can be explained? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand... If 'script.x' is located in /etc/scripts/subdir/ why are you calling '/etc/scripts/script.x' instead of '/etc/scripts/subdir/script.x'?

Comment: That's the point - i do not call '/etc/scripts/script.x' but '/etc/scripts/subdir/scripts.x'. Nevertheless, the shell responds with the message above...

Comment: Then I'm sure is a problem of permissions. 'chmod 755 ./script.x' and then try to run the script with root privileges. Also you could some changes to figure out what is going like. Like adding '#!/bin/bash' in the first line in the script. Change the extension to .sh. Copy all code into a new file and run it from the new file.